# Nginx Ingress Controller Installation Error, "dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to setup a kubernetes cluster with kubeadm and vagrant. I faced an error during installing nginx ingress controller was timeout when the pods is trying to retrieve the configmap through kubernetes API. I have looked around and trying to apply their solution, still no luck, this is the reason I come out with this post.

Environment:

I'm using vagrant to setup 2 nodes with ubuntu/xenial image.

```
kmaster
-------------------------------------------
network:
Adapter1: NAT
Adapter2: HostOnly-network, IP:192.168.2.71

kworker1
-------------------------------------------
network:
Adapter1: NAT
Adapter2: HostOnly-network, IP:192.168.2.72
```

I followed the kubeadm to setup the cluster

[[Setup kubernetes with kubeadm]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

And my kube cluster init command as below:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.2.71
```

and apply calico network plugin policy:

```
kubectl apply -f \
https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/etcd.yaml

kubectl apply -f \
https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml
```

(Calico is a plugin I currently successful installed with, I will come out another post for flannel plugin which the plugin unable to access the service)

I'm using helm to install ingress controller followed  the tutorial
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

That's the error occurred once I applied helm deploy command when I describe the pod

[image: Helm Ingress Error]

Appreciate someone can help, as I know the reason was the pod unable to access kubernetes API. But not this already should enable by kubernetes by default?

My kubesystem pods status as below:
[image: kube system pods]

Another solution provided from kubernetes official website:

1) install kube-proxy with sidecar, I still new with kubernetes and I'm looking for example how to install kube-proxy with sidecar. Appreciate if someone could provide an example.

2) use client-go, I'm very confuse when I read this post, it seems that using go command to pull the go script, and I have no clue how's it working with kubernetes pods.

Comment: (a) watch out with vagrant clusters as it is **very important** that nothing in the cluster try to bind to that NAT interface; kubespray is notorious for overlooking that, so kubeadm may fall prey to it, also. You can actually side-step that issue entirely by using `bridge` for the interface, if that's acceptable in your situation. (b) i/o timeouts are almost always a CNI failure; did all the calico Pods come up successfully?

Comment: Yes, calico pod were up successfully. I can access to a sample service and deployments.

Comment: and other Pods can access 10.96.0.1:443? you also mentioned "the error occurred once I applied helm deploy command" -- is that the same error? Please do consider fleshing our your question to include more details; log messages, tests you have already run, anything

Comment: The other pod not able to access kunernetes api also.

Comment: I have added more info, and I try to ping 10.96.0.1 from other port, it's not working also.... Maybe I have to try in the real environment like GCD, AWS,...

Comment: My guess is that your vagrant network is clashing with calico ip pool.  Can you try changing vagrant network to something like 172.18.18.xxx.

Answer (score 1):

You guys are right, I have tested with digital ocean's droplet and it works as expected,  I hit another error is "forbidden, user service account not permitted". Look like the pods is able to access the kubernetes api already. I also tested install istio which I encountered the same issue before, and now it worked in digital ocean droplet.

Thank you guys.